# DI with UnitOfWork and Repository patterns in WindowsForm use Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I have problem when I build project WindowsForm application Dependency Injection.
Here this is my code in Program.cs file.

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        // Register your Web API controllers.
        //builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<DITestDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
        //builder.Register(c => app.GetDataProtectionProvider()).InstancePerRequest();

        // Repositories
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ProductCategoryRepository).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();

        // Services
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ProductCategoryService).Assembly)
           .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
           .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();

        Autofac.IContainer container = builder.Build();

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(container.Resolve<Form1>());

        `
```

And here this is my code in Form1.cs

```
private IProductCategoryService productCategoryService;
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    public Form1(IProductCategoryService productCategoryService, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.productCategoryService = productCategoryService;
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        LoadProductCategory();
    }

    private void LoadProductCategory()
    {
        var data = productCategoryService.GetAll();
        gridControl1.DataSource = data;
    }
```

And I get the error

> DependencyResolutionException: Unable to resolve the type 'DITest.Service.ProductCategoryService' because the lifetime scope it belongs in can't be located. The following services are exposed by this registration:
>   - DITest.Service.IProductCategoryService'

I think I make a mistake when I start Form1. Anyone can help me?
Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this error because you are using `InstancePerRequest` in a Windows Form Application. 
`InstancePerRequest` is intended to be used by a web application, it allows to have one instance per web request.

In order to make your application works, just remove the `InstancePerRequest`. *Autofac*  will use `InstancePerDependency` scope if no scope is specified.

You can find more information about scope in the documentation : [Instance scope](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html)

Comment: Oh thanks you. But I have get error "NoConstructorsFoundException: No accessible constructors were found for the type 'DITest.Data.Infrastructure.UnitOfWork'." I don't know how to fix this. Can you help me?